# Free expansion of real gas problem with equation of state $pV\exp(a/RTV)=nRT$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, gas

The volume  of a rectangular box is divided into two equal parts
by a solid non-permeable partition P. On one side of the partition
P there is a vacuum, while the other side is filled with a real gas
having equation of state
$$pV\exp(\frac{a}{RTV})=nRT$$
where $$ and $$ are constants, The gas was initially at a uniform
temperature $T_0$. Then the partition was removed
instantaneously, and the gas was allowed to expand to fill the full
volume of the box and come to equilibrium.
The final temperature of the gas, in terms of its specific heat $_$ will be? To solve this sum i assumed that the setup was thermally insulated so $dQ=0$,
Then from first energy relation i found $ΔU$ by integrating from $V/2$ to $V $. Then i tried finding net work done but $\int pdV $ was coming to an infinite series with an exponential term. But the answer given is $$ T-(\frac{na}{C_v})ln 2.$$
But it's not coming in logarithmic, can anyone please point where my concept is going wrong and guide me to correct solution. Please help.

Comment: ΔU=$C_v$ΔT+[nRT{exp($\frac{-a}{RTV}$)$–$exp($\frac{-2a}{RTV}$)}]. This is what I got.

Comment: The work is zero, so U is Unchanged.

Comment: Why the work is zero? It's a real gas so wouldn't there would be work done against internal attraction?

Comment: You mention a constant $b$, but I don’t see it.

Comment: @Chemomechanics ,i actually don't know why they have mentioned b. The equation of state is some simplified version of Diecterici equation which has (V–b) instead of V .

Comment: The given answer can't be correct anyway, as $na/c_V$ doesn't have units of temperature.

Comment: Yes you are right @chemomechanics  , the answer given in book is wrong, thanks for clearing my doubt. Sorry for putting a wrong information question in PSE platform.

Comment: The work is zero because the process takes place inside a rigid container.

Comment: Yes I understood thanks@Chet Miller.

Comment: For this particular equation of state, the temperature change turns out to be zero.